# Find the terminal point when the distance is not in terms of $\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

From Stewart Precalculus 5th edi, P407

[image]

I am not sure what to do here, in the textbook, Steward didn't provide any example as to finding the terminal point when the distance $t$ is an integer. I know how to find when the distance is in terms of $\pi$.

Am I supposed to replace 1 with $\frac{\pi}{3}$, 2 with $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and give an estimation?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the figure you can see that he has labels around the edges of the circle. The numbers $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$. The terminal point when $t=1$ would correspond to the location labelled with a $1$. The angle at that point is exactly $1$ radian which is about $57$ degrees. By counting the number of tics to get to $1$ you can determine how many radians each tick is worth and then use that to answer questions that involve a fractional number of radians such as $t=2.5$.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at it a bit and was able to figure it out. First, draw a right triangle with the hypotenuse connecting the outer diameter (point 1) of the circle and the origin. The horizontal leg is the $x$ coordinate and the vertical is the $y$ coordinate of the terminal point. We know that $1$ radian is approximately $57$ degrees, and the radius of the circle is $1$. Knowing this, we can set up the trig ratio :

$\sin(x) = \dfrac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$

"$\sin(57) = \dfrac{y}{1}$"  which can be simplified to "$\sin(57) = y$"

If you plug this into a calculator, it will give you the length of the vertical leg, AKA the $y$ coordinate, which is approx $0.8$. Now that you know two of the side lengths of the triangle, you can use the Pythagorean theorem to figure out the third length, which is approx $0.5$. Since the horizontal leg is $0.5$ and the vertical leg is $0.8$, your coordinates will be $(0.5,0.8)$ when $t=1$. You can use this strategy for all the other problems. Hope this helps!